# How do I save a Pandas Dataframe object as a PDF after adding style to it?

Tags: python, pdf, pandas, dataframe, styles

I have a Dataframe and have added styles to it to highlight portions, etc. and can render to HTML easily, but when attempting to save as a PDF, the styling is lost. Anyone have any tips?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.linspace(1,10,10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))], axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

def color_negative_red(val):
    """
    Takes a scalar and returns a string with
    the css property `'color: red'` for negative
    strings, black otherwise.
    """
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color

s = df.style.applymap(color_negative_red)
```

I want to now take `s`, which is a `pandas.core.style.Styler` object and convert the DataFrame to a PDF while saving all of the formatting (highlighting negative numbers as red). Is there a simple way to do this or is the style mechanism in Pandas still under development?

Comment: Are you using ipython/jupytet?

Comment: @merlin, yes, I am using a jupyter notebook instance to build out a Proof of Concept for a styling data frame function.

Comment: I am trying to save this last two hours, seems like there isn't any easy way (I haven't found any hard either). Pitty, I'd think, that this feature would be very easy to add, since the html raw code should be somewhere under the hood.

Comment: @quapka Thanks for trying, yes, I also tried everything ranging from the difficult back to the easy to pipe this into a savable format, but could not figure it out. I ended up taking screen shots for now, and am sure that it will be an available feature in the future. Thanks again for trying!

Comment: I am thinking of writing this myself. Will what I end up with.. If it would be useful I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Not the greatest solution but it does produce a pdf

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.linspace(1,10,10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))], axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

def color_negative_red(val):
    """
    Takes a scalar and returns a string with
    the css property `'color: red'` for negative
    strings, black otherwise.
    """
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color

s = df.style.applymap(color_negative_red)

import pdfkit
import tempfile

options = {
    'page-size': 'Letter',
    'margin-top': '0.75in',
    'margin-right': '0.75in',
    'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
    'margin-left': '0.75in',
    'encoding': "UTF-8",
    'lowquality': False,
    'quiet':'',
    'custom-header' : [
        ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
    ],
    'cookie': [
        ('cookie-name1', 'cookie-value1'),
        ('cookie-name2', 'cookie-value2'),
    ],
    'no-outline': None
}

tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
with open(tmp.name, 'w') as f:
    f.write(s._repr_html_())
with open(tmp.name, 'r') as f:
    pdfkit.from_file(f, "s.pdf",options=options)
f.close()


display(s)
```